# Betamax is not recording in Grails

Tags: grails, betamax

I have a class that contains a RESTClient, and it performs a simple get request.

The test is built as follows

```
@Rule Recorder recorder = new Recorder()

@Betamax(tape = 'meetupEventsList')
void testListEvents() {
    when:
    def instance =  new Client('<apikey>')
    def events = instance.listEvents('<groupname>')

    then:
    log.info("List of events: {events}")
}
```

The BetamaxConfig.groovy: (Found in grails-app/conf/BetamaxConfig.groovy)

```
betamax {
    tapeRoot = new File('test/resources/tapes')
    ignoreLocalhost = true
}
```

The test is running, however I'm not getting anything in the test/resources/tapes directory (in either /test or /src/test/. I'm also not getting any logging from the betamax framework.

What am I doing wrong? Are there any other ways to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Which version of the plugin are you using? Also have you seen the plugin author's note about the plugin not working on recent versions of Grails? (e.g. anything past Grails v2.1.5) https://github.com/robfletcher/betamax/issues/134

Comment: Also I'm on Grails 2.4.